# NodeJS BotFramework integration with FB: only page admin can interact?

Tags: botframework

**Background**

I have a NodeJS chatbot created using MS BotFramework.  Everything goes fine when setting up in Azure and so on.

The test of Chatbot is fine in Azure.  And I follow [this guide from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-facebook) to integrate Chatbot to FB, it seems OK also.

**My Question:**

When I (as a page admin) test the bot in FB, it works fine.  However, when other people comes in (no matter like my page or not) and send the same test text to the Chatbot.  No response.

I am pretty sure that the page and the app are live and public.

[image: pages_messaging is added in app review]

[image: my app is public]

Can anyone please tell me what's happened and how to fix this?  Are there any additional rights I need to add?

Thank you very much in advance for all your help.

Comment: Has your bot been 'approved' by facebook yet?

Comment: @JasonSowers  Thank you.  Can you please tell me what does "approved" by facebook mean?  When the app is live and capabilities are added, does it mean that it is approved?  Actually I saw some green ticks on "Messenger", "Web Hook" and so on.

Comment: There is an approval process you need to go through to get your app/bot available to the public on facebook

Comment: @JasonSowers So what you mean is, even if I get green ticks of my messenger service, shown "Added" in "pages_messaging" and the app is live and public, I am still not "approved" by FB?  Thank you again.

Comment: yes, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review

Comment: @JasonSowers  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Users will not be able to get your automatic replies while your app is in development (not submitted), except if you add them in your "testers" group.

You can do this in your app settings, in the Roles tab located here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YourAppId/roles/roles/

[image: Tester adding]

Comment: Thank you.  But from the image you can see that my app is Live and published.  So it is not in development mode.  Since it is live, I "assume" that I don't need another "tester" account to verify that.

Comment: "But from the image you can see that my app is Live and published": we don't see that on your image, sorry. As @Jason explained, it seems you did not passed Facebook's approval so it is only live for testers

Comment: Thank you for your response.